# Why is there an elementary-geometry tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Is there a reason for the [elementary-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-geometry) tag?  I just noticed it now—it has 9 questions, which appear to be at a fairly wide variety of levels of geometry, and none of which are tagged with the much-more-often-used [geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry) tag.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: Is it possible to change these 9 instances to "geometry" without too much trouble? I would support that.

Comment: @Jim: Yes, a moderator can merge [tag:elementary-geometry] into [tag:geometry] to make that happen.

Comment: Shouldn't this go on the huge tag merging and synonyms thread?

Comment: People in differential geometry think "geometry" means them.  People in algebraic geometry think "geometry" means them.  However, (elementary-geomety) will exclude these, I guess.

Comment: @GEdgar: If the point of [tag:elementary-geometry] is just to exclude differential and algebraic geometry, then I'm definitely against having the tag at all.

Comment: Isaac, @AsafKaragila Related: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32960/why-dont-we-have-an-elementary-geometry-tag-or-why-dont-we-use-geometry-to-me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done. [Extra characters to satisfy the length filter.]

Comment: Related: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32960/why-dont-we-have-an-elementary-geometry-tag-or-why-dont-we-use-geometry-to-me