# Why don't we have an elementary-geometry tag? Or why don't we use geometry to mean elementary geometry?

Tags: discussion, tagging

**Notes/Observations/Opinions**:

1. Related: [Why is there an elementary-geometry tag?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2390/why-is-there-an-elementary-geometry-tag)
2. The tag usage guidance for [geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry) goes

   - > For questions about geometric shapes, congruences, similarities, transformations, as well as the properties of classes of figures, points, lines, and angles.
3. To me this sounds essentially like 'geometry for highschool/grade school/pre-university/primary school/secondary school'. Of course you click and see the full tag info and see that geometry can also be tagged for university 'geometry' that maths majors (and some physics majors) take.

   - 3.1. Actually, the full tag info I find is kind of weird. Everything before 'Sub-fields of Contemporary Geometry' suggests pre-university geometry while everything afterwards suggest university 'geometry'.
4. We have [probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability) vs [probability-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability-theory) and [set-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/set-theory) vs [elementary-set-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-set-theory)
5. I also think it's kinda redundant to tag [geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry) with every single [differential-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-geometry) or [complex-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-geometry), but eh I guess it's like tagging [probability-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability-theory) with every [martingale](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/martingale) or ([stochastic-calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stochastic-calculus) or [stochastic-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stochastic-analysis)) with every [stochastic-differential-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stochastic-differential-equations)

**Questions**:

1. Why don't we have an '[elementary-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-geometry)' tag?
2. Or why don't we use [geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry) to mean '[elementary-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-geometry)'?
3. Is the tag [coordinate-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coordinate-geometry)/[analytic-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analytic-geometry) supposed to be like the '[elementary-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-geometry)' tag?

Comment: You have already linked to: [Why is there an elementary-geometry tag?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2390) This discussion is somewhat related, too: [Should we require a tag that which specifies difficulty of a question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10271) Other areas where elementary tag was discussed at some point were: [general topology](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/conversation/elementary-general-topology-tag) and [probability](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29718/tag-management-2019/30631#30631).

Comment: BTW the syntax for tags does not support spaces. So `[tag:elementary geometry]` in your post is not rendered tag, but `[tag:elementary-geometry]` should work just fine.

Comment: @MartinSleziak re syntax thanks! re other comment, will read later

Comment: The full tag info, especially those about "contemporary geometry", fails to direct users to the correct usage. It was edited last year and I don't think it reflects the current usage of the tag. IMO it gots even worse after the more recent edit to include 7, 8..... Also, I guess most of the mathematicians disagree that topology is a subfield of geometry.

Comment: I'd say topology grew out of geometry, and then it outgrew geometry.

Comment: Isn't Euclidean-geometry the same thing as elementary-geometry?

Comment: @Favst [tag:euclidean-geometry] ooohhhhhh niiiiiiiiice yes. well i guess. good question. good observation.

Comment: @Favst, don't think so, you can talk about affine group, affine subspaces etc.

Comment: Maybe [tag:elementary-mathematics] would be better? Otherwise you may also need [tag:elementary-algebra], [tag:elementary-arithmetic].

Comment: non-elementary algebra has plenty of tags already (abstract algebra, group theory, etc.)  Same thing for non-elementary arithmetic being numerical methods, I suppose.

Comment: @Alexey i kind of agree with that actually. i wonder if elementary-maths tag would be like the homework tag from before though. lol.

Comment: @user694818, non-elementry geometry also has tags already ([tag:metric-spaces], [tag:geometric-topology]). Non-elementary arithmetic indeed may include many subjects ([*A Course in Arithmetic* by Jean-Pierre Serre](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4684-9884-4)).